# C# Get Focused Position / Index In Textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, focus

How Can I Get Focused Cursor Index To Make Left Key Suppress
Examples :

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && textBox1.Text.FocusIndex == textBox1.text.IndexOf(">")+1)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

If Focus Cursor Reach The Next Character Of "**>**" Disable The Left Arrow ...
How Can I Get Focused Index or Position ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for "Focused Cursor Index" you mean Caret position you can use the property `SelectionStart` of your TextBox.
Like :

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left == textBox1.SelectionStart == textBox1.Text.IndexOf(">"))
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Comment: I Only Want To Left Arrow Don't Work Until Reach The '>' Character

Comment: Yeah , I Tried But How To Check When Cursor Reach `>` ?

Comment: Using SelectionStart in conjunction with IndexOf like in your example

Comment: Can You Send Example Please :) ?

Comment: Oooo , Now I Get Thanks , It Works :))

Comment: aaa Nice ;-) Feel free to accept the answer. Good work.